# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am facing the same issue after updating to Java 11
Can someone please help here
spring-Kafka: 2.7.6,
Kafka-clients:2.7.2,
kafka-avro-serializer:6.1.1,

It is working locally but not working on the server (docker container)

```
Error:
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:441)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:291)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createRawProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:743)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createKafkaProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:584)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.doCreateProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:544)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.getTheProducer(KafkaTemplate.java:683)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:569)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:380)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.configure(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:376)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please show your client configurations ... And if you try to manually import `KafkaAvroSerializerConfig` anywhere, what error do you get?

Comment: `        if (schemaRegistry != null && schemaRegistry.isEnabled()) {
            schemaRegistryProps.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistry.getUrl());
            schemaRegistryProps.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, schemaRegistry.isAutoRegister());
            schemaRegistryProps.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.USE_LATEST_VERSION, schemaRegistry.isUseLatestVersion());
            schemaRegistryProps.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY, schemaRegistry.getNameStrategy());
        }
`

Comment: Please [edit] your post rather than use comments, and you didn't answer what happens when you manually try to import `KafkaAvroSerializerConfig`